# PyRSS2Gen and embedding html in description tag

Tags: python, rss, cdata

I want to format the content of the description using html tags.  When I try to enclose the content in `<![CDATA[content<p>here]]>` it doesn't work properly, as it escapes some of the brackets, displaying O.K. in some RSS viewers, but displaying the `]]>` in others.

If I try to avoid the CDATA and use escaped characters throughout, this mostly works, but $lt;p$gt; gets displayed as `<p>` rather than a new code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `'&'` instead of `'$'` for the escapes. Is it a typo?

Comment: Figured out the source of the problem, but still looking for the best way to fix it. PyRSS2Gen passes a string to saxutility.xmlwriter, which escapes all characters that need escaping in XML, including the angle brackets around the CDATA.  As a kluge, I then wrote code to find the just the CDATA strings at that start and end and changed them back.  Still looking for ideas on a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into my problem some more and the problem is that PyRSS2Gen uses python's sax library, which has no concept of CDATA, at least when writing out XML. My solution was just to drop PyRSS2Gen and directly use minidom, which does understand CDATA sections.  That did mean some extra lines of code.

Once the html text inside my description tag was properly enclosed in a CDATA section, the raw xml looked fine and it also displayed the way I wanted it in 3 RSS readers I tried.

Answer (score 0):

According to examples in the RSS 2.0 specification you can use both CDATA and the escapes ["Encoding & item-level descriptions"](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/encodingDescriptions.html).